# Continous surjective map from $S^1$ to $S^n$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Is there any continous surjective map from $S^1$ or $[0,1]$ onto $S^n$, for some $n\geq 2$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. Start with a [space filling curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_filling_curve) $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]^2$. Induction gives you a continuous onto $\gamma_n \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]^{n}$. Identifying the boundary to one point is a quotient map $\pi \colon [0,1]^n \to S^n$, together with $\gamma_n$, we have $\pi \circ\gamma_n \colon [0,1]\to S^n$.

Comment: I see your point. I will try to figure out the details. Thank you for your help.